# Does the parent git repository contain the full source tree of a git submodule?

Tags: git, github

Does the parent git repository contain the full source tree of a git submodule?

Lets say that the remote repository for a git submodule goes offline, can we still access the source tree of the particular submodule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the submodule is cloned just like any other repository (inside the submodule directory), but the history is not integrated in the "parent repository", the parent only knows the remote location and a commit ID.

If the remote goes offline, the users that already cloned the parent repository (and its submodules) would still have the whole source code and the history of the submodule in their PCs, just like any other cloned git repository.

Answer (score 3):

Git repositories do not contain submodule sources. They contain a pointer to the submodule repository and (usually) a specific commit at which the submodule should be checked out.

Working copies generally do contain the submodule source code, so anybody who has cloned the repository and initialized the submodules will be able to continue working.